# Need help creating a header with a clean navigation

Tags: html, css, xhtml, header, navigation

Can someone help me figure out how to create the navigation displayed in the header on top of this page?

http://themes.iki-bir.com/ikaros/

If someone could give me some direction to learning how to make these types of navigations, I'd really much appreciate it.

Comment: I would download the css and html and dissect it if you want to learn!

Comment: How would I make the navigation menu though, and make it so it extends to the top and bottom of the header?

Comment: its a very broad question, have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: The link doesn't seem to be anything special. I would look into jQuery if you are not yet familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use This dropdown menu plugin, its a **Jquery css dropdown plugin** which uses jquery and css both...

You have to do some changes to the js and css to try make it as similar as possible...

http://www.saptarang.org/jquery-css-dropdown-menu-2-levels

Thank you...